# Azure Blob SAS gives an error while container SAS is working on the same blob

Tags: azure-blob-storage, azure-python-sdk, azure-sas

My application needs access to the blobs inside my storage and sinc I dont want to ditribute any credentials I'm develpoing a backend endpoint to supply limited SAS token to the client app after authentication.

I thought on generating a blob SAS token (thus following the [principle of least privilege](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_privilege) and even though I think it worked in the past and I managed to retrieve the blob, it stopped working and I'm getting the below error.
Generating a container SAS token and using it on the sme blob - works.

I also tried to generate a blob token from Azure Portal and use it in the same way and that actually worked as expected

Any idea what is wrong with what I'm doing?

this is the code I'm using to generate the blob token (I'm using the Python SDK):

```
start_time = datetime.datetime.now(datetime.timezone.utc)
expiry_time = start_time + datetime.timedelta(seconds=int(900))
sas_token = generate_blob_sas(
                account_name=account_name,
                container_name=container_name,
                blob_name=blob_name,
                account_key=account_key,
                permission=BlobSasPermissions(read=True),
                expiry=expiry_time,
                start=start_time
            )
```

using this generated token with a blob URL from the container, gives the following error (HTTP status code 403) when trying to retrieve the blob (GET request):
[image: Error when using blob token]

When I change the code to generate a container token, by using the following code:

```
start_time = datetime.datetime.now(datetime.timezone.utc)
expiry_time = start_time + datetime.timedelta(seconds=int(900))
sas_token = generate_container_sas(
                account_name=account_name,
                container_name=container_name,
                account_key=account_key,
                permission=BlobSasPermissions(read=True),
                expiry=expiry_time,
                start=start_time
            )
```

Everything works, and I manage to retirieve the blob.

Both [generate_blob_sas](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-storage-blob/azure.storage.blob?view=azure-python#azure-storage-blob-generate-blob-sas) and [generate_container_sas](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-storage-blob/azure.storage.blob?view=azure-python#azure-storage-blob-generate-blob-sas) comes from azure.storage.blob Python SDK (currently using version 12.19.0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of the Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature"

The error occurs when you pass with wrong parameters in the **`generate_blob_sas`** function.

I used the below code to generate the **`SAS`** token for the blob it created successfully using Python with the same package **`azure-storage-blob==12.19.0`**.

In my environment, I have stored an image with the blob name **`spring-flowers.jpg`** in the Azure blob storage.

**Portal:**
[image]

**Code:**

```
import datetime
from azure.storage.blob import generate_blob_sas, BlobSasPermissions

account_name = 'venkat789'
account_key = 'xxxxxxxx'
container_name = 'demo'
blob_name = 'spring-flowers.jpg'

start_time = datetime.datetime.now(datetime.timezone.utc)
expiry_time = start_time + datetime.timedelta(seconds=int(900))

def get_blob_sas(account_name,account_key, container_name, blob_name):
    sas_blob = generate_blob_sas(account_name=account_name, 
                                container_name=container_name,
                                blob_name=blob_name,
                                account_key=account_key,
                                permission=BlobSasPermissions(read=True),
                                start=start_time,
                                expiry=expiry_time
    )
    return sas_blob
sastoken = get_blob_sas(account_name,account_key, container_name, blob_name)
url = 'https://'+account_name+'.blob.core.windows.net/'+container_name+'/'+blob_name+'?'+sastoken
print(url)
```

**Output:**

```
  https://venkat789.blob.core.windows.net/demo/spring-flowers.jpg?st=2023-12-11T08%3A37%3A15Z&se=2023-12-11T08%3A52%3A15Z&sp=r&sv=2023-11-03&sr=b&sig=/JcSw%2Bxxxxxx
```

[image]

When I copied the same blob sas URL and pasted it into the browser it worked perfectly.

**Portal:**

[image]

**Reference:**

[azure.storage.blob package | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-storage-blob/azure.storage.blob?view=azure-python#azure-storage-blob-generate-blob-sas)

Comment: Thank you @Venkatesan for the elaborate answer. you are right!
when I called generate_blob_sas I passed the wrong blob_name, which also explains why it used to work in the past (when I passed the right blob_name) and why generate_container_sas also works (because it is not dependent on the blob_name)

Comment: Refer this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/service-sas-examples

Comment: Thanks. already been throw this multiple times...just forgot what I did in my API signature (tried to send ID instead of blob_name)